# Confidence intervals for 6-point Likert scale

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, rating

I was asked to compare certain ratings between two different groups. The distribution of ratings looks something like this:

    `Value    Count   Percent
      1        4      1.32%
      2        5      1.65%
      3       14      4.62%
      4       48     15.84%
      5      173     57.10%
      6       59     19.47%`

1 is "Very bad", 6 is "Very good".

Would it be acceptable to compute confidence (or Bayesian probability) intervals as if the data were normal? If not, what's a better solution. The people who I report to are very non-technical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confidence intervals for frequency tables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298398/confidence-intervals-for-frequency-tables)

Comment: What parameters are you proposing to compute intervals for?